# Problema eñes "ñ" en SQL y PHP

Tags: php, sql

Dispongo de un fichero .sql para ser cargado en phpmyadmin mediante la opción de importar .sql.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la opción "Conjunto de caracteres del archivo:" he elegido tanto "utf-8" como "iso-8859-1".

Al inspeccionar los elementos de la base de datos en las tablas, me encuentro con que sí acepta las "ñ".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Lo que ocurre es que al ejecutar una consulta en php me muestra la "?" en lugar de la "ñ"**, he añadido la opción siguiente pero no funciona:
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base). Esta pregunta se ha planteado de diversas maneras aquí. La codificación hay que revisarla en diferentes niveles. En tu caso casi seguro que el problema se encuentra en el **nivel 3**.

Comment: También puedes jugar con el encoding con que se sirve la página. A lo mejor PHP la recibe bien y tu webserver la despliega mal?

Comment: En mi editor Notepad++ tengo la codificación UTF-8 asignada, no sé dónde tengo la errata.

Comment: Puedes utilizar `utf8_encode(nombre)` o `uft8_decode(nombre)` a la hora de mostrar tus datos desde el PHP.

Comment: El problema es que al crear la conexión a la base de datos desde PHP no estás estableciendo la codificación , ahí debes establecer UTF-8. **Nivel 3** de la pregunta enlazada más arriba. No implementes soluciones a medio camino, perderás en rendimiento. Y verifica que tienes UTF-8 en todos los niveles de tus datos.

Comment: @Francisco Romero utilizar `utf8_encode` y `uft8_decode` para esto es un parche. No debería de utilizarse en este contexto. Justo como comenta A. Cedano la solución pasa que l codificación sea la adecuada en todos los niveles e intercambio de datos.

Comment: @omaza1990   ¿Cúal es la codificación establecida en tu base de datos y en la conexión a la misma? Asegúrate de usar el meta de html para indicar también la codificación `<meta charset="UTF-8">` y que el navegado lo intérprete como tal.

Comment: Mi problema está en el -Nivel 4- (anteriores niveles probados, sin cambios) debido a que en los datos de las tablas en localhost/phpmyadmin de mi base de datos, salen los datos con "ñ" y "´" en un formato incorrecto.